# Unable to import ggplot in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-ggplot

i am unable to import ggplot in python 3.5. Can any body help me out on this? i think i have to install through pip install but do not know how to do it.
 Below is the error.

ImportError: No module named 'ggplot'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `pip install ggplot` from the command line, then you should be able to import it in a Python project.

Here's some documentation on using pip: [pip help](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing/#use-pip-for-installing)

Don't be afraid to use Google, the Python community is big and has probably answered many of your questions already.